# Intel RAID controllers and CPU processor

Tags: raid, intel

Looking at the [configuration guide for the Intel Server Chassis / Intel Server Board dating "Junly 2012"(sic!)](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/s5500bc/sb/s5500bc_config_guide_27.pdf), in the section of *"Production RAID Controllers"* it mentions "Supported in Single processor configuration only" or "Dual processors configuration".

So if I have 2 CPUs present in my system, and install one of the "single processor" RAID controllers, it won't work?

Answer (score 2):

In general, if a vendor is saying "unsupported" it may mean several things:

1. it will work but don't call us if you have problems
2. it won't fit
3. it won't work
4. it will fry your system and the engineer installing the option

I do not know the ServerChassis, but I would suspect it is 2. - the card which is labeled for "single processor configuration" is a full-height PCIe card, so it might simply get in the way of the cooling assembly of the second CPU:

[image: singleproc RAID]

Whereas the "dual processors configuration" card is a low-profile card, taking less physical space in the chassis:

[image: dualproc RAID]

It is also possible that one or the other is not supported due to cooling issues as the guide mentions things like

> Battery Back-up unit (BBU) is not supported in the SR1630BC due to thermal limitations

In general, if you hear a vendor telling you "not supported" it means something which should not be done. Also, don't be afraid of asking Intel themselves if you need a definite and authoritative answer.